# The correct usage of has

Tags: existentials

> The box has many things.

Is this a correct sentence? Or would it be better to write it as

> There are many things in the box.

Answer (score 1):

"The box has many things" is correct, but it would perhaps be more appropriate to say:

- The box **contains** many things.
  OR
- The box has many things **inside**.

However, I find the other sentence, "There are many things in the box," to be much better.

Comment: Many teachers wouldn't advise their students to use *there are..* because it sounds indirect and wordy.

Comment: @user178049 Actually, the two structures are essentially different -- in the ones starting with "The box", that phrase is obviously the subject, while in the one with "There are", anticipatory "there" introduces "many things" as the real, logical subject. The focus is therefore different too.